# Ошибка билда докера в туториале

Tags: docker

При команде

```
docker build -t docker101tutorial .
```

Вылезает ошибка с ругательством на Jinja2

```
ERROR [build 2/2] RUN mkdocs build                                             0.6s 
------
 > [build 2/2] RUN mkdocs build:
#23 0.501 Traceback (most recent call last):
#23 0.501   File "/usr/local/bin/mkdocs", line 8, in <module>
#23 0.501     sys.exit(cli())
#23 0.501   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1130, in 
__call__
#23 0.501     return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
#23 0.501   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1055, in 
#23 0.502     rv = self.invoke(ctx)
#23 0.502   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1657, in 
invoke
#23 0.502     return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
#23 0.502   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1404, in 
invoke
#23 0.502     return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
#23 0.502   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/click/core.py", line 760, in i
nvoke
#23 0.503     return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
#23 0.503   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mkdocs/__main__.py", line 187,
 in build_command
#23 0.503     build.build(config.load_config(**kwargs), dirty=not clean)
#23 0.503   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mkdocs/config/base.py", line 2
16, in load_config
#23 0.503     from mkdocs.config.defaults import get_schema
#23 0.503   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mkdocs/config/defaults.py", li
ne 1, in <module>
#23 0.503     from mkdocs.config import config_options
#23 0.503   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mkdocs/config/config_options.p
y", line 8, in <module>
#23 0.503     from mkdocs import utils, theme, plugins
#23 0.503   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mkdocs/theme.py", line 6, in <
#23 0.503     from mkdocs.utils import filters
#23 0.503     @jinja2.contextfilter
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mkdocs build]: exit code: 1
```

Первый раз трогаю докер, решил использовать для курсовой, но встретил сложности ещё в туториале. Всё, что я встретил это рекомендации запинить джинжду с помощью пип тулс, но так ли это и как делать не имею не малейшего понятия

Comment: Не обращайте внимания, я просто скипнул и все. Тоже не срабатывала из коробки. Вся дока лежит в docker.com и ничего там особого нет

Comment: Проблема не в докере, а в том, что пользователь насоздавал. Если у Вас на компе что то установлено, то это не значит, что оно автоматом и в докер образе есть. Нужно писать правильный докер файл, который все установит